# using $.extend() to add more cases to a switch statement function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jpc3982p/4/)**

I have a function called `parseData` to render html presentation from returned json data in the main js file.

```
var data = {
  "title": "This is news"
};


$("button").click(function(){
    var feedformat = $(this).data('format');
    item_html = parseData(feedformat, data);
    $('.feedback').append(item_html);
});    

function parseData(type, data) {
   var item_html = ''; 
   switch(type) { 
       case 'story':
       item_html = '<h5>'+data.title+'</h5>';
       break;
  }
    return item_html; 
}
```

My question is, is it possible to use `$.extend` to add more cases from another script file that is dynamically pulled in on click using `getscript`? Suppose I have a new case called `oldnews`. That case contains a lot of html tags but won't be used often, so I don't want to store it in the main js file and would like to bring it in only when people want it.  Call I use something like the following in another script file to extend `parseData` which is in the main js file?

```
(function($){
    var addcase = $.fn.parseData;
    $.fn.addcase = function( type,data ) {
            case 'oldnews':
       item_html = '<div>'+data.title+',but outdated</div>';
      break;

   };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. `$.extend` is for modifying objects, not functions.

Comment: Rather than trying to generate code, why not use some form of lookup table which you *can* merge (even if some elements are functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds pretty easy, actually.  What you're really trying to do is map the names of data formats to functions that produce HTML output.  You could easily encode what you've already demonstrated here with this:

```
var parseFunctions = {

    story: function(data) {
        return '<h5>' + data.title + '</h5>';
    },

    oldnews: function(data) {
        return '<div>' + data.title + ', but outdated</div>';
    }

}
```

When it is time to output some html you can do this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var format = $(this).data('format');
    if (typeof parseFunctions[format] == 'function')
        $('.feedback').append( parseFunctions[format](data) );
});
```

This works because Javascript treats functions like any other value.  You can assign them to variables, copy them, etc..  With this technique you can extend the base `parseFunctions` object with a another object containing functions.  The main thing you have to look out for is key collision.  (Two people trying to define a function for data type 'some_type'.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of switch/case statements, you could do something more extensible like looping over a container of news item qualifiers and their associated data. In JSON this might look like:

```
{
  "story": {
    "html": "<h5>%s<\/h5>"
  },
  "oldnews": {
    "html": "<div>%s, but outdated<\/div>"
  }
}
```

If you have a JavaScript object like that, you make it visible to parseData, which gets the "html" value of whichever one matches "type" and replaces "%s" with the title. Whenever new "cases" are pulled in, you use _.extend or $.extend to add to the structure.